# How to upload an array of files?

Tags: php, arrays, file, file-upload, image-upload

I'm trying to build an array of files by submitting a form several times, then move those files to a directory, but it's not working. Every uploads just overrides the previous and then it doesn't even move that one (the upload_to_file() function doesn't do anything)

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="home.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="8000000">
        <input class="upload_btn" type="file" name="images[]" id="image_file">
        <input type="submit" id="img_submit" class="form_button" name="submit_image" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

It is important that there is only one upload button which can be used to upload many files.

I need them to be stored in an array so I can display their ['name'] anywhere with a loop.`for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $i++){}`

Then once another form is submitted it calls a function to move each file in the array to a directory.

Function inside an included php file:

```
function upload_to_file(){
$image_paths = array();
$target_dir = "uploads/images/";
$path = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['images']['name'][0]);

if(isset($_FILES['images']['name'][0]) && $_FILES['images']['size'][0] > 0)
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][0], $path)) {
        $image_paths[0] = "uploads/images/";
    }
}
return $image_paths;

}
```

I'm only testing it with the first element in the array, but will need to make a loop later.

Comment: Those uploads are send as separate requests, php has no idea of multiple requests being part of something bigger. So either you have to use a "session" for persistence and collect the information spanning _all_ requests from the session, _or_, more flexible, you need to implement that on the client side, so that things like a file index are created and shown client side. That's called an "upload manager".

Comment: I tried with session with something like array_push($_SESSION['images'], $_FILES['image_file']); which worked fine, until the move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['images'][0]["tmp_name"], $path) part. It kept returning false even though if I output $_SESSION['images'][0]["tmp_name"] it is there.

Comment: So you are saying you upload the files with one form and organize them with another form but you don't store them in a database (the path and such)?

Comment: The `move_uploaded_file()` only works during the request handling itself. So right when a file is uploaded, no matter what yo manually save into the session variables. So either fully process each uploaded file or, if really required, move it to a temporary place your take care of manually. That will require cleanup, though. Not a good architecture.

Comment: Ok I tried moving the files one by one as soon as the form is submitted and at least move_uploaded_file() works. I didn't want to do that because now if i just want to remove as a submitted file it has to go and delete it, instead of just removing it from an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program, which help you to upload multiple files. in the code "sub" is the submit button name. "upload" is the name of file controller, the uploaded files are stored in the directory called "img" that you have to create on your root folder.

```php
<?php

if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    if (count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0) {
     for ($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
      $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
      if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
        $shortname = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
        $filePath = "img/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {
          $files[] = $shortname;                    
        }
      }
    }
  }
  echo "<h1>Uploaded:</h1>";    
  if(is_array($files)){
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($files as $file){
      echo "<li>$file</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
  }
}
?>
```

HTML Code is given

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input id='upload' name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Upload Now">
</form>
```